# Autocomplete in different languages OR: How to store different languages for web-applications

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, localization

I working on a website and have a mysql-table called 'items', like:

```
item_id | item
```

(The second column is just for identify the item_id.)

In a language1.php I store a array with the item_id and the name of the item itself in language1, like:

```
$items = array(
1 -> 'Apple',
2 -> 'Orange',
...
);
```

Depending on the language of the user, the correct language-file is included.

There should be an autocomplete-input-box for the items-array (< 1000 items/ array). I guess, its not a good solution, to search the array in the language1.php with php ("search_array" or some function like this), but i think there is no way to maintain this system and search by mysql, isn't it?

How are you store different languages for websites and make them searchable?

Is it necessary to store all languages in a specific column in mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably add an `items_localization` table with columns like

```
item_id,
locale,
content, (in your base language of choice)
translation (the translated content)
```

that has a foreign key to `item_id`, and either a compound primary key on `item_id, locale`, or an autoincrement id field and a unique index on `item_id, locale`.  Some folks like working with single-column, autoincrement primary keys because of the framework they are working with, so if this describes you, use the latter solution.

Alternatively if you wanted a wider localization solution you could just have a `localization` table with columns like

```
localization_id,
locale,
content,
translation
```

that can store any sort of localization. Then you items_localization table could just be a many-many join table with columns like

```
item_id,
localization_id
```

You could just do a join query to get the localization you are looking for.  For using the first proposed table structure:

```
SELECT i.*, il.translation
FROM items AS i
INNER JOIN items_localization AS il on i.item_id = il.item_id
WHERE il.locale = ? AND il.translation LIKE "%?%"
```

Where you substitue your values for current locale and the autocomplete search phrase for the `?`'s.

Comment: Your `items_localization` really shouldn't contain a `content` field. It would be redundant to have it in every translation, plus it wouldn't be used anyway except when looking at the rows directly.

Comment: I personally like to have some place where I can see what the string is in my language of choice.  I know this would be a bit redundant storing in the fashion, but to me this isn't really that big of a performance issue, as I would never query that field anyway.  You could perhaps normalize even more than mentioned in my second schema option by having a content table and then just reference that content id in the translation table, but to me it is more convenient to have this field side-by-side with the translated content in the same table.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm not normalizing everything, either. But that may be a good use for a view (if the SQL server has them implemented).